# Is union of three disjoint open nonempty set is disconnected?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, connectedness

I know the definition of connected set such that:
[definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Uk6a.png)

But is the union of three disjoint set is disconnected? For example:
(1,2) $\cup$ (3,4) $\cup$ (5,6)

I know that (1,2) $\cup$ (3,4) or (3,4) $\cup$ (5,6) are disconnnected but when they are (1,2) $\cup$ (3,4) $\cup$ (5,6) I do not know what to say, it is connected or disconnected.

Is this disconnected or connected?

Comment: $(1,2)$ and $(3,4) \cup (5,6)$ are disjoint non-empty open sets whose union is the given set.

Comment: So I can say (1,2) ∪ (3,4) ∪ (5,6)  is disconnected, right?

Comment: Yes, it is not connected.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was confused.

Answer (score 1):

**Definition:**
A topological space  $X$ with topology $\tau$ is *disconnected* if there are non empty open sets $A,B$ such that $A\cup B=X$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$ otherwise the topological space said *connected*.

Now under this premise we are assuming $X= (1,2) \cup (3,4) \cup (5,6) $ with the usual topology In $\mathbb{R}$ given by the basis $\beta=\lbrace (a,b) \mid a,b \in \mathbb{R} , a<b\rbrace$.

what can cay about the set $X$?

As Kavi point:

$A=(1,2)$ is open and $B=(3,4)\cup (5,6)$ is also open and
Their union is the whole $X$ and their intersection is also empty (you can check) therefore X is disconnected.